# error with connecting to an external kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I installed the kubernetes cluster using kubeadm, everything is fine on the servers themselves, the master and worker node are visible

```
--apiserver-cert-extra-sans=*.*.201.87
```

I make a connection from another network from a local PC, having previously copied admin.conf to ~/.kube
I get an error

```
E0125 13:47:12.606617 794306 proxy_server.go:147] Error while proxying request: x509: cannot validate certificate for *.*.201.87 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

we tried to request certificates again and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case

```
export no_proxy=$no_proxy,11.62.201.87
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are literally using `*.*.201.87`, then this is wrong and you should use proper IP address or DNS name.

If you masked the actual IP with `*` in this example, check the cert served during TLS handshake:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port>
# save cert in cert.pem
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem
```

Check what entries are listed under `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`.

Comment: there is an ip of this server X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:kubernetes, DNS:kubernetes.default, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, DNS:secr-k8s-master-1, IP Address:10.96.0.1, IP Address:11.62.201.87

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted

```
x509: cannot validate certificate for ..201.87 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

indicates that the certificate presented by the Kubernetes API server does not contain the necessary IP SANs to match the IP address you are using to access the cluster.

Try regenerating the certificates for the Kubernetes API server with the appropriate IP SANs. You can use the `kubeadm alpha phase certs all --apiserver-advertise-address=<your-IP\>` command to achieve this. See this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/)

Make sure also that the **KUBECONFIG** environment variable is correctly set to the location of your **admin.conf** file. This file should contain the necessary certificate and key data to authenticate with the Kubernetes API server.